# PHP get post data of selected item

Tags: php

I have the following HTML code

```
<select name="select">
    <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
  <optgroup label="Add teachers">
    <option value="add-teacher">Add a teacher</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Design">
    <option value="frontpage">Redesign <b>front</b> page</option>
    <option value="ratepage">Redesign <b>rate</b> page</option>
    <option value="gamepage">Redesign <b>game</b> page</option>
    <option value="ratepage">Redesign <b>suggestions</b> page</option>
    <option value="ratepage">Redeisgn <b>news/future-updates</b> page</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bugs/glitches">
    <option value="bugs">Report a bug/glitch</option>
    <option value="bugs">Report an exploit/loophole</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
</select>
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
<textarea name="suggestion" class="textarea" placeholder="How can we improve this?"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="btn">
</form>
```

How would I send the selected one of those items to `send.php` using POST method? Or GET, I don't mind. Something like `$_POST['select'];`, maybe?

Comment: Put the `select` inside your `form`.

Comment: Thanks. If you'd like to post that as an answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `select` needs to be inside the `form`:

```
<form action="send.php" method="POST">
<select name="select">
    <option value="Select...">Select...</option>
  <optgroup label="Add teachers">
    <option value="add-teacher">Add a teacher</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Design">
    <option value="frontpage">Redesign <b>front</b> page</option>
    <option value="ratepage">Redesign <b>rate</b> page</option>
    <option value="gamepage">Redesign <b>game</b> page</option>
    <option value="ratepage">Redesign <b>suggestions</b> page</option>
    <option value="ratepage">Redeisgn <b>news/future-updates</b> page</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bugs/glitches">
    <option value="bugs">Report a bug/glitch</option>
    <option value="bugs">Report an exploit/loophole</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label=""></optgroup>
</select>

<textarea name="suggestion" class="textarea" placeholder="How can we improve this?"></textarea>
<input type="submit class="btn">
</form>
```